# display the same column twice with different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that contains Enable and Disable values, which is associated by an event id, in this event table I have the user datatime, I would like to create a query and display the time the enabled event was triggered and in the same row. the time the disable was triggered

```js
SELECT
    valv.valvOf, valv.cam,
    cod.descOf Habilita, cod.descof Desabilita
FROM
    {oj (aspersao.dbo.events events LEFT JOIN aspersao.dbo.valv valv ON events.valv_id = valv."id") LEFT JOIN aspersao.dbo.cod cod ON events.cod_id = cod.id}
WHERE
    valv.cam = '1'
and 
    Habilita = 'Habilitou valvula'
and 
    Desabilita = 'Desabilitou valvula'
```

Comment: You can't refer to output aliases in the `where` clause. Look more into table aliases. `valv.descOf = 'X' and cod.descOf = 'Y'`

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't work because I'm assigning two constraints to the same column

Comment: yes, I'm aware of it, but I would like something like

Comment: No, you have copies of the same table and they need to be given an alias so you can refer to them individually.

Comment: @Piotr that is an ODBC join syntax thing from the days of non-standard outer joins. It works though I doubt it's necessary.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/outer-joins?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after correcting your code so that you are not trying to refer to columns by their aliases in the `WHERE` clause, your code is nonsense. No row will have a column equal to two different values.

Likely you want to pull in the table twice. I'm also getting rid of the ODBC specific curly brace syntax.

```
SELECT
    valv.valvOf, valv.cam,
    cod1.descOf AS Habilita, cod2.descof AS Desabilita
FROM
    aspersao.dbo.events AS events 
    LEFT JOIN aspersao.dbo.valv AS valv ON events.valv_id = valv."id"
    LEFT JOIN aspersao.dbo.cod AS cod1 
         ON events.cod_id = cod1.id     
         AND cod1.descOf = 'Habilitou valvula'
    LEFT JOIN aspersao.dbo.cod AS cod2
         ON events.cod_id = cod2.id     
         AND cod2.descOf = 'Desabilitou valvula'
WHERE
    valv.cam = '1'
```

This is pretty much a guess because there really isn't enough info in your question.

**EDIT**: I had the wrong test string in the `cod2.descOf =` line; I've fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, your code works, just a few tweaks to my app